# Taking the "semi definite" integral of a function with Heaviside step function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^tH(\tau-2)(e^{-2(\tau-2)}-e^{-3(\tau-2)})\,d\tau$$

As I understand it, I can't just set the lower boundary to $2$, because this is a *semi definite* integral, because of the upper boundary being the variable $t$.

However, that makes the expression I get look way more ugly than if I could let the lower boundary be set to $2$.

When I input this into Mathematica, I get the expression:

$$\frac{1}{6}\left(1+2e^{6-3t}-3e^{4-2t}\right)H(t-2)$$

Which is the integral with the lower boundary set to $2$, but the factor $H(t-2)$ stays.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $t>2$, you just do the integral. If $t<2$, the integral is zero. A convenient way to write this is the step function.

Comment: To add to this, the $H(t - 2)$ in the solution isn't quite the same as the $H(\tau - 2)$ in the problem.  (For one thing, the variable is different.)  So it's not that that factor somehow stays.  It's just that the answer behaves differently depending on how $t$ compares with $2$, which is different from (although related to) that the function in the problem behaves differently depending on how $\tau$ compares with $2$.